# Unable to expire a .NetCore cookie

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies

I'm using .NetCore and Cookie authentication.  Account management (login, logout, etc) is all managed through an API as opposed to using the Identity UI.  My understanding is that the server can't actually send anything to the client to actually remove the cookie, rather, I would need to "expire" the cookie on the server and return it to the client.

So here is my setup

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddAuthentication("mycookie")
  .AddCookie("mycookie", options => {
     options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
     options.SlidingExpiration = true;
     options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
     options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
  });
```

In my `ApiController` I have the following:

**AccountController.cs**

```
[HttpGet("signout")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SignOut()
{
    var temp = new AuthenticationProperties()
    {
       ExpiresUtc = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
    }
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("mycookie",temp);
    return Ok();
 }
```

However, my cookie never seems to expire when I call `signout`.  I noticed in the browser dev console, the cookie says `Expires on: Session`.  I would've expected to see a date/time there.

How do I get rid of the cookie or expire it when signout is called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the **[Clear-Site-Data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Clear-Site-Data)** response header. Among other things, it allows you to clear cookies on the client's browser.

In my example below, I'm clearing the user's cache and cookies for my domain.

```
   public IActionResult Logout()
    {
        this.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Clear-Site-Data", new StringValues(new string[] { "\"cache\"", "\"cookies\"" }));
        return Ok();
    }
```

First be sure to [check browser support for this header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Clear-Site-Data#Browser_compatibility).

If your browser does not support Clear-Site-Data, then you should be able to expire them like so:

```
this.Response.Cookies.Append("cookieName", "deleted", new CookieOptions()
{
   Expires = DateTimeOffset.MinValue
});
```

When this logout response returns to the browser, I'm able to see the cookies disappear (using Chrome 73.0.3683.86, *Developer Tools/Storage/Cookies/{myDomain}* )

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I'm using the latest version of FireFox

Comment: I just tested it in latest FireFox (66.0.1) and it works great.
Make sure you're passing the value "\"cookies\"" and not "cookies".
Also note that this will only clear cookies that have a Domain matching the origin of the response URL.

Comment: You're right, it works -- and I'm an idiot.  Realized my Action was never getting called because I had `[HttpPost]` attribute and was calling with `GET`.  Doh!

Comment: Incidentally, I found that once I was calling the Action with the right protocol, the `SignOutAsync()` call was sufficient to log out -- I didn't actually need the extra HTTP headers or the Expiration value